# REST API not receiving correct DateTime from React JS frontend

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, date

I have REST API's and calling these API's from my React front end. Rest of my data goes smoothly and correctly except time.
I am using `new Date()` object. REST API receives the date correct but time is a not correct.

"alert(new Date());"
gives correct value though.

Comment: What is expected and what do you get?

Comment: @ochs.tobi I expect current date and current time but i get current date and like 5 hour early time

Comment: Maybe the server has an incorrect time or is in another timezone?

Comment: both the API and frontend is on localhost right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var now = new Date();
var utc = new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Please try this, utc is the time you are interested in I guess.

Comment: It works thank you... I changed the offset "60000" to get my desired results.