# ASP.NET Core DateTime Rest API with Javascript converts to UTC instead of java

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a problem with sending data from my react application with data `Sat Oct 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)` from javascript function `new Date()`.  When receiving from the my ASP.NET Core Rest Web API application, it converted to `{10/29/2021 4:00:00 PM}` for reason.  I think what received from ASP.NET was a `UTC` time conversion from the javascript `DateTime` that send from my react application.  Is there a way to not convert the and retain the same data as javascript `DateTime` when it receives data from my ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: Don't pass around JS `Date` objects - just pass around Unix timestamp values, which are always UTC.

Comment: @Dai how do I do that?

Comment: [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422330/rest-api-not-receiving-correct-datetime-from-react-js-frontend)

Comment: Hi @AliK, I wanted the selected date to be sent to my rest api.. it seems it converts it to the a UTC instead of a selected datetime.. All I want is the selected date value.

Comment: If you have a property like DateTime Date{get;set;} on your model .net should bind any incoming dates by default.  It is a good idea to show your controller and model and how you are sending the date from client side (code).

Answer (score 0):

When I sent the time from the front-end page, the time received by the controller was converted. You can use the following methods to convert:

```
dateTime.ToString("r")
```

Result:

[image]